# split a key-value pair in Python

Tags: dictionary, split, key, key-value

I have a dictionairy as follows:

```
 {
    "age": "76",
    "Bank": "98310",
    "Stage": "final",
    "idnr": "4578",
    "last number + Value": "[345:K]"}
```

I am trying to adjust the dictionary by splitting the last key-value pair creating a new key('total data'), it should look like this:

```
 "Total data":¨[
 {
 "last number": "345"
 "Value": "K"
  }]
  }
```

Does anyone know if there is a split function based on ':' and '+' or a for loop to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I would advice to include some code you tried into your question, else it might get flagged and removed. Second, what language are you trying to solve this problem with? JSON can be process by many languages. Third, you are going to have to detect the formatting of the key and the value if you want to do the split you wish to do. Learn to use regular expressions to be able to extract that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to accomplish that could be getting the last key from the dict and using split on `+` for the key and `:` for the value removing the outer square brackets assuming the format of the data is always the same.

If you want `Total data` to contain a list, you can wrap the resulting dict in `[]`

```
from pprint import pprint

d = {
    "age": "76",
    "Bank": "98310",
    "Stage": "final",
    "idnr": "4578",
    "last number + Value": "[345:K]"
}

last = list(d.keys())[-1]
d["Total data"] = dict(
    zip(
        last.strip().split('+'),
        d[last].strip("[]").split(':')
    )
)
pprint(d)
```

Output (tested with Python 3.9.4)

```
{'Bank': '98310',
 'Stage': 'final',
 'Total data': {' Value': 'K', 'last number ': '345'},
 'age': '76',
 'idnr': '4578',
 'last number + Value': '[345:K]'}
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/b6EWqC)

Comment: Thanks! I have also tried something different (more tedious) by creating a string first, which I split and inserted into a new dictionary, which I then inserted in the old dictionary while deleting the old key value pair. Also, there are many dictionaries in my actual example, some of which contain the last key value pair, while some do not. These dictionaries are generated with a for loop. Would you happen to know how to integrate the above code into a fore loop such that the operation is performed for only those dictionaries which do contain  "last number + Value" key value pair?

Comment: @clinicalprogrammer You might use an if check to see if the last key equals `last number + Value` See an example with a loop and multiple dictionaries https://ideone.com/AavEvM

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my late reply, that did work!